# MySQL Query: column BETWEEN A AND B OR C

Tags: mysql, sql, database, operators, between

I wondered if I can get a query like this to work:

```
"DELETE FROM table WHERE id (BETWEEN 1 AND 5) OR = 8;"
```

The thing I want to achieve: I want to say; get me the results between some values or also the value if my id = 8.

Unfortunately I only found queries and questions how to search for
things like this.

```
"DELETE FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND `email`='sarah@sarah.com';"
```

Or would I have to do it likewise:

```
"DELETE FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 OR id = 8;"
```

Thanks for a short input on that...

Cheers

Comment: I have to agree with Mark it's only need me 10sec to google this [link]http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: well I mean I understood what BETWEEN does. And I personally don't like w3schools answers that's why i banned it from my google results. but yes I may should have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (id BETWEEN 1 AND 5) OR id = 8
```

To SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id BETWEEN 1 AND 5) OR id = 8
```

Comment: Ok. thanks. I thought there might be a shorter syntax.